# Windows CE Data Transfer using a Wifi Peer to Peer connection through an ODBC driver to a Backoffice Database

Tags: windows-mobile, ftp, odbc, windows-ce, file-transfer

Motorola Windows ce MT2090 Handheld. VB.NET application using a Wifi connection signs into a Oracle/MSSQL/MYSQL database Server. Download the data to the MT2090 device. Additional Data is added and when finished the VB.NET application uploads the data back to the database Server. During data input there is "no access" to a WiFi network. I seached the net and could not find a data provider for an ODBC peer to peer connection. Not sure why since this solution is standard on all MS Windows desktop applications. I am a vp.net/ oracle programmer.

Answer (score 2):

The Compact Framework doesn't support ODBC - and it's generally considered a legacy technology replaced by ADO.NET.

For ADO.NET access to a SQL Server database, use the `SqlClient` class.

For ADO.NET access to an Oracle database, use something like [dotConnect Mobile](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/editions.html).

It looks like there's even [something for MySQL](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/05/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-on-the-net-compact-framework/).